# Render Farms render blank image frames

Tags: rendering

Hi I've tried rendering through both concierge render and garageFarm.net but both farm are rendering blank frames,
I have an active camera, and when I hit ctrl f12 it works fine.
What's happening, files are packed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the culprit is in the rendered layer settings;

(View Layer Properties tab)

you will need to use the "Use for Rendering setting".

The Render Single Layer setting is ignored in command line rendering, and it’s only used in rendering from Blender interface.

Once you use this setting, you should get the correct output rendered from the farm

[image: Use for rendering location]